# A probability theory problem in skiplist's C implement

Tags: c, algorithm, probability, skip-lists

These days I am looking at skiplist code in `Algorithms in C, Parts 1-4`, and when insert a new value into skiplist is more complex than I think. During insert, code should ensure that the new value insert into level `i` with the probability of `1/2^i`, and this implement by below code:

```
static int Rand()
{
    int i, j = 0;
    uint32_t t = rand();
    for (i = 1, j = 2; i < lg_n_max; i ++, j += j)
        if (t > RANDMAX / j)
            break;
    if (i > lg_n)
        lg_n = i;
    return i;
}
```

I don't know how the `Rand` function ensure this, can you explain this for me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `RANDMAX` is intended to be `RAND_MAX`.

Neglecting rounding issues, half the return values of `rand` are above `RAND_MAX / 2`, and therefore half the time, the loop exits with `i` = 1.

If the loop continues, it updates `i` to 2 and `j` to 4. Then half the remaining return values (¾ of the total) are above `RAND_MAX / 4`, so, one-quarter of the time, the loop exits with `i` = 2.

Further iterations continue in the same manner, each iteration exiting with a portion of return values that is half the previous, until the `lg_n_max` limit is reached.

Thus, neglecting rounding issues and the final limit, the routine returns 1 half the time, 2 one-quarter of the time, 3 one-eighth the time, and so on.

`lg_n` is not defined in the routine. It appears to be a record of the greatest value returned by the routine so far.

Comment: Thank you very much, and I have full understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `Eric Postpischil` very much for his answer, I have understand how to ensure the probability. And I have a more understood answer:
The `t` is a random value between `0` and `RANDMAX`,  and we assume that the loop will run 2 times. In the first loop,  value of `t` is smaller than `RANDMAX/2^1`,  means that value of `t` fall into the range from `0` to `RANDMAX/2` , the probability of this is `1/2`. In the second loop, remember the fact that value of `t` is in the range of  `(0, RANDMAX/2^i)`,  value of `t` is smaller that `RANDMAX/2^2`,  means that value of `t` fall into the range from `0` to `RANDMAX/2^2`,  the probability of this is also `1/2`, because the range of `(0, RANDMAX/2^2)` is only `1/2` of the range in first loop, and the first loop show value of `t` is in the range of `(0, RANDMAX/2^1)`. And notice that the probability of second loop is conditional probability，it‘s based on the probability of first loop, so the probability of second loop is `1/2*1/2=1/4`.
In a short, every loop will bring a `* 1/2` to last loop's probability.